# 127.0.0.1:8000 keeps on loading in a laravel project

Tags: laravel

I have a laravel project but when I use the command "php artisan serve" and type the url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/ , its just keep on loading without output nor error appear.

Comment: You must be having an error in your code, check in the terminal when you launch the site. You will see an issue written in terminal, so the server crashes and stop working hence loading forever.

Answer (score 10):

I solved this by running this command instead of PHP artisan serve.

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public/
```

Then try to load again 127.0.0.1:8000 in your browser.

Comment: You can also change the port by "php -S 127.0.0.1:8080 -t public/" and load it to your browser 127.0.0.1:8080

Answer (score 4):

Try disabling your anti-virus or check your firewall.
I disabled my Avast anti-virus and it's working fine for me now.

Answer (score 2):

Run commands

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Even after completing these steps, if Laravel is still showing error, check `your_project/storage/logs/laravel.log`.

Comment: C:\\Users\\NOR-AIN\\Desktop\\system\\SimpleBlogProject\\artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#6 {main}

Comment: C:\\Users\\NOR-AIN\\Desktop\\system\\SimpleBlogProject\\artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#6 {main}

Comment: clear error log and try php artisan serve again, now update your Question with complete errror log

Answer (score 2):

The port 8000 might be used by other in your computer. Try to change port by running in your project in cmd:

```
php artisan serve --port=1000
```

then type http://127.0.0.1:1000/ on your browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try these three commands for clearing cache config:

```
    php artisan config:cache // clear config cache
    php artisan config:clear // clear config cache
    php artisan cache:clear // clear cache
    php artisan optimize  // To reoptimize the class loader
    php artisan route:cache // clear route cache
    php artisan view:clear // clear view cache
```

Comment: answer updated try the new ones as well mostly this:  php artisan view:clear

Comment: APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug

enable error loging in your .env file at the root of the project and see if application has any error

Comment: Try this and allow php server to fire wall:
php -S 0.0.0.0:8000

Comment: when there were 2 project opened in IDE on localhost  it kept to load only one's page. These  'artisan optimize' did the job .

Answer (score 1):

It sometimes happen because of too many **redirection** and also sometime because of **middleware** . so see your whole flow for that page.

Also see your `cdn` which included in your page because it take too many time if you have too many cdn and your connection is slow. And also try to clear all cache.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this problem also when I first launched out into Laravel.
Your port 8000 is most likely occupied by another service or program.
Simply go to your terminal where your project is open, and enter the following command

```
php artisan serve --port=1000
```

Then, return to your browser and enter the address, replacing 8000 with 1000, as in

```
127.0.0.1:1000
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

**If you are using xampp**

just restart Apache and MySql

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues may be possible for that.

1. You have used CDN JS and CSS
2. Check you route/web.php
3. Check you log error log file storage/logs/laravel.log

Check above points this will sure give you positive result.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I uninstalled Xampp  and reinstalled it(I'm assuming you are using Xampp too).It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, MySQL was running fine. unless it wasn't. It was showing that it was running okay, but it wasn't. Cause when restarting the Xampp MySQL server. It stated that MySQL couldn't start due to a blocked port or...
I then
renamed Xampp/mysql/data to Xampp/mysql/data_old
created a new folder named data there
and copied everything from Xampp/mysql/backup to Xampp/mysql/data.
then restarted the Xampp MySQL server,

my laravel project also finished loading and served the application.
so the problem was with mysql server not starting properly.